# Ftp put local file lock

Tags: linux, ftp

Could anyone tell me if the standard ftp put implementation on linux takes any lock on the local file while it's reading?  (I realize this should be a relatively simple test, but I don't have a box available.)

(And for context, we have a file that is replaced on a regular interval but every so often is locked by someone.  I traced it down to a specific user/machine and an ftp put script is the only thing I see that could potentially take a lock.)

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

-rw-r--r--. 1 ftpuser ftpuser 12031 Nov 30 17:50 index.php

May this be what you are looking for, i transfered a file using my ftp client to my server, and did nothing to it, im running vsftpd.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear.  I meant while it's reading the file to transfer.  Not that it would change the permission of the file itself.  I'll update!